# Difference between valueMap() and mapsValue()?

Tags: node.js, gremlin

i am a beginner in using graph database. As per my knowledge,valueMap() returns the array of properties of a particular vertex.But in tinkerpop documentation, i have found another method like mapsValue(). may i know the difference please.thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you found that? Can you provide a link? I can't even remember having something called `mapsValue` in TinkerPop 2.

Comment: @Daniel kuppitz,i have found in tinkerpop but this link is from deprecated methods of gremlin.org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__.mapValues()

Answer (score 0):

`mapValues()` has been deprecated.

You need to use `select()` instead of `mapValues()` which is used for creating alias for traversals.

Comment: thank you.i have just got to know about deprecated methods and fields because of your response.thank you it helped me.